# Object 'function' has no attribute 'files'

Tags: python

sorry if this is a bad one but, Im learning and while doing so I'm making pointless things.

```
def singulateDataInDir(SRCdir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SRCdir, topdown=True):
        for name in files:
            filesInSRCdir = os.path.join(root, name)
            return filesInSRCdir
        for name in dirs:
            dirsInSRCdir = os.path.join(root, name)
            return dirsInSRCdir

def copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST(SRCdir, DESTdir):
    singulateDataInDir(SRCdir)  
    for files in singulateDataInDir.filesInSRCdir:
        shutil.copy2(files, DESTdir)
```

so In singulateDataInDir im just separating files and folders in a directory and listing them out and in copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST im trying to use shutil.copy2 and then feed it the list of file paths (what I thought was filesInSRCdir) and copy to a new destination. I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(True)
  File "main.py", line 38, in main
    code.copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST(srcOpt, destOpt)
  File "/Users/jcrd/Documents/csProjects/pythonProjects/screenshotCollecting/code.py", line 32, in copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST
    for files in singulateDataInDir.files.filesInSRCdir:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'files'
```

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: You must call a function (append parentheses, maybe with arguments if necessary) to receive a result and work with it further.

Comment: The error message indicates that the code you're running is not the same as the code you posted.  The code you're running has `singulateDataInDir.files.filesInSRCdir`.  The code you posted has `singulateDataInDir.filesInSRCdir`.  Try to make the code you're running match the code you posted.

Comment: You can't just access a function's local variables from outside it with the dot operator. You'd have to explicitly save them like that, as in `singulateDataInDir.files = files` within the function, for them to be accessible like that. And they would only exist after you call the function at least once.

Comment: I should've added that I had been tinkering with it before posting, what I originally had and thought was the correct way was what I have posted and the error message was when I tweaked it thinking I had to specify moreso. either way the error code is the same

Comment: @TomKarzes im running what I posted, as I copied and pasted it. As for the difference in the error code, I took it from after I had tried to specify what I was asking for within the function, which I thought was returning `'filesInSRCdir'`